# Visual Studio Upgrade Advice

Tags: visual-studio, iis, windows-7, windows-xp, windows-server

My work is currently using Visual Studio 2005 with Windows Server 2003 (IIS 6). We're looking to finally upgrade our systems.. Our computers are still on Windows XP for goodness sake. We have two options, upgrade to VS 2013 which means we'll have to upgrade our computers to Windows 7 OR upgrade to VS 2010 in which case we can keep Windows XP. We're still on Windows XP because apparently nothing at work is compatible with Windows 7 at the moment, we're working to upgrade everything eventually.

I have the following questions..

1. Can Visual Studio 2013 run on IIS 6?

   - If not, is it possible to upgrade to IIS 7 or 8 on Windows Server 2003 or would we have to upgrade the server as well?
2. Can Visual Studio 2010 run on IIS 6?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Take in consideration that `Windows XP` (and Windows Vista) are becoming obsolete in a few weeks.

With that been said better make a plan for updating your OS to Windows 7 or 8. So that means you should go with `IIS 7` and above.

As per VS I think try 2013 since we are already in 2014.